# Error : "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'typedef' "

Tags: c++, compilation, cplex

I have a compilation problem using C++ language and IloCplex framework.

I first tried to compile the entire project using a makefile, but i got an unexpected error, with a class header call **AbstractModel**, so as to ensure that this error is not due to other file, i decided to just compile this class with this command :

> g++ -o AbstractModel.o -c -I/path/to/cplex/include 
>   -I/path/to/concert/include -DIL_STD AbstractModel.cpp

Then i realized that i got the same error message, here is the **AbstractModel** class :

http://pastebin.com/B9YiqKUS

and the type.h class :

http://pastebin.com/trQ6BDBK

The error is the following :

> In file included from AbstractModel.hpp:12,
>                    from AbstractModel.cpp:7:
>   type.h:6: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘typedef’
>   In file included from AbstractModel.cpp:7:
>   AbstractModel.hpp:50: error: ‘Vector’ does not name a type
>   AbstractModel.hpp:51: error: ‘Vector’ does not name a type

Any suggestions ?

P.S : Cplex works fine on this computer, i have another project with the same kind of class that compiles perfectly with the same command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CustomType.hpp must be #included before AbstractModel.hpp because CustomType.hpp defines the typedefs that AbstractModel.hpp uses.

It is impossible to see from what you have pasted whether or not that is indeed the case.

Ideally your AbstractModel.hpp header will `#include "CustomType.hpp"` itself rather than relying on it being done.

Comment: Result stay the same, and again, i have another project in which i do the same operation, and this works :/

Comment: Well i just found the problem, i just copy definition from my previous project and a caracter was missing for the 

> ILOSTLBEGIN

macro.

Sorry for bothering you, and thanks for your comments, it helped me to figure out

Comment: do you really need that macro? And I don't see a matching ILOSTLEND

Comment: Well, the first time i tried to use IloCplex i got shit ton of problem for compiling my project, and got lot of conflict with the STL, i find several macros related to it into code sample through the web and i let it like that, but you right, it is not necessary, this macro just imply a "using namespace std" inclusion, and don't require at all an ILOSTLEND macros :)

Comment: Essentially then you are secretly using namespace std in your header files.

Comment: Yes, i never had trouble for that though, i remove it anyways since i never used it.

Answer (score 0):

Your include guards in your header are wrong:

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_TYPE_H

        typedef IloNumArray Vector;
        typedef IloArray<IloNumArray> Matrix;
        typedef IloNumVarArray VariableVector;    
        typedef IloArray<IloNumVarArray> VariableMatrix;    

        #define CUSTOM_TYPE_H //This should be just under the #ifndef, not here.
#endif
```

Comment: Yes it does not make any difference, putting it first is just a convention and do not impact the typedef.